# matplotlib: set zorder for path effects

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am curious if it is possible to explicitly set the drawing order of path effects in `matplotlib`, i.e. not just with respect to multiple path effects on one artist but with respect to the entire plot.

For example, I am using `SimpleLineShadow` to make highlights behind a set of lines. However, I want the highlights to fall below all of the parent lines in the drawing order. As it is, if line `A` is plotted before line `B`, then the highlight for line `A` will be drawn on top of line `B`. I'd like some way to set a `zorder`-type argument on the highlight path effect so that line `B` is drawn above line `A`'s highlight path effect even when `plot()` is called on line `A` first.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to first draw all the highlights and in a second pass all the "normal" lines.

A first step collects all the lines that need the effect into a list (`lines`). Then, onto these lines the `SimpleLineShadow` is set, but not the `path_effects.Normal()`.

Next, the lines are all copied. `get_xdata()` and `get_ydata()` can copy the positions. `update_from()` copies all the other elements (color, marker, linestyle, ...). The path_effect gets overriden with only the 'normal' effect.

In the code below, the left plot draws the lines with the highlighting in just one step. The right plot first draws the highlight and on top of that the 'normal' line.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patheffects as path_effects

fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=2)

x = np.arange(200)

# on the left ax, use the all-in-one appraoch
lines = [axs[0].plot(x, np.random.normal(0, 0.1, 200).cumsum(), color='k', linewidth=2)[0] for _ in range(5)]
for l in lines:
    l.set_path_effects([path_effects.SimpleLineShadow(offset=(0, 0), shadow_color='gold', alpha=1, linewidth=5),
                        path_effects.Normal()])

# on the right ax, first only set the special effect, then create copies and draw the 'normal' lines
lines = [axs[1].plot(x, np.random.normal(0, 0.1, 200).cumsum(), color='k', linewidth=2)[0] for _ in range(5)]
for l in lines:
    l.set_path_effects([path_effects.SimpleLineShadow(offset=(0, 0), shadow_color='gold', alpha=1, linewidth=5)])
lines_normal = [axs[1].plot(l.get_xdata(), l.get_ydata())[0] for l in lines]
for l, ln in zip(lines, lines_normal):
    ln.update_from(l)
    ln.set_path_effects([path_effects.Normal()])

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: demo plot]

Comment: Does this answer your question?